# Change iTerm2 font color depending on the word

Tags: terminal, iterm2

Example, if "GET" is being printed on the terminal, i want that GET get colores in color green. if the sign # is printed, i want that only this character get colored.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences>Profiles>Advanced>Triggers/Edit!